# 403 forbidden with URI routing in Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I'm trying to set up routing to a page on my site with Codeigniter, but I just get a 403. I can't understand why.

Code in the routes config file is:

```
$route['photo/(:num)'] = "viewphoto/view/$1";
$route['photo'] = 'photo';

$route['photos'] = "photospage/index";
$route['photos'] = 'photos';

$route['default_controller'] = 'homepage';
$route['homepage'] = 'homepage';
```

When going to mysite.com/photo/2 (for example) it works fine, as does the homepage. But when going to mysite.com/photos I just get a 403 Forbidden error message.

I can't work it out, the routing is set to exctly the same as the mysite.com/photo/2 routing.

The controller it's pointing to is called photospage and the function inside it is called index.

If I go to mysite.com/photos/index it works though...

Any help is most appreciated :)

**EDIT:**

Change the routes config file to the following but it still doesn't work when I go to mysite.com/photos. I changed the controller function to a 'view' instead of 'index' but it still won't work :(

```
$route['photos'] = "photos/view";
$route['photo/(:num)'] = "viewphoto/view/$1";
$route['default_controller'] = 'homepage';
```

homepage and photo/$id still work fine though.

Comment: By default if a controller is called without a function it will automatically run the index function. Also why have you got two routes for photos?

Comment: Becuase one is a route for mysite.com/photos which shows a page full of thumbnails and the other is mysite.com/photo/$id which shows a specific photo page when a user clicks on a thumbnail.

Comment: I think you may be confusing CI. The second set of rules have $route['photos'] pointing to different controllers, how should it know what one to pick?

Comment: It still doesn't work even with 1 route for $route['photos']. Still get a 403 error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your [rewrite](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html) rule should be:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

You have to remove your `index.php` entry from your `/application/config/config.php`

Verify that is setup correctly the **403 forbidden** error might be due to a faulty `.htaccess` rewrite.

Comment: This almost works. I had to remove the \ before the index.php on the 3rd line though, as my site is stored in a subdirectory from my main domain for dev purposes and it just starts loading the directory above... The routing now works but no images or CSS are loaded...

Comment: Ok I have figured it out! There were two issues: 1) I forgot to add the css directory into the 2nd line of the rewrite. 2) I have a folder called 'photos' which stores a load of photos that are used on the pages (which i've now renamed), I guess it was conflicting with the routing. Thanks Jakub!

Comment: In my case it was the directory with the name identical to the route that caused this issue.  Deleting the (unneeded) directory solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

OK, let's take a look at these one by one (assuming your domain is 'example.com' and you have 'index.php' hidden via '.htaccess'):

```
$route['photo/(:num)'] = "viewphoto/view/$1";
```

This will grab any url like this:  `http://example.com/photo/36` and route it to the `/application/controllers/viewphoto` controller, and call the `view` method and pass it 36 as the parameter.

---

```
$route['photo'] = 'photo';
```

This will grab any url like this:  `http://example.com/photo` and route it to the `/application/controllers/photo` controller, and call the `index` method with no parameter.

---

```
$route['photos'] = "photospage/index";
```

This will grab any url like this:  `http://example.com/photos` and route it to the `/application/controllers/photospage` controller, and call the `index` method with no parameter.

---

```
$route['photos'] = 'photos';
```

This will grab any url like this:  `http://example.com/photos` and route it to the `/application/controllers/photos` controller, and call the `index` method with no parameter.
**This route will never get called because it duplicates the one right before it**

---

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'homepage';
```

This will grab any url that hasn't been caught thus far and route it to the `/application/controllers/homepage` controller, and call the `index` method with no parameter.

---

```
$route['homepage'] = 'homepage';
```

This will grab any url like this:  `http://example.com/homepage` and route it to the `/application/controllers/homepage` controller, and call the `index` method with no parameter.

My guess is this has to do with not having an `index` method in the controllers. If that is not the case, then we would need to see the contents of the `.htaccess` file.

Comment: I don't think it has anything to do with the index function. I changed it to a view function and it still doesn't work. It should work though, I don't get why it doesnt. Here's the contents of my .htaccess file (which I have modified to hide the index.php): `RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L] `

Comment: I have updated my question with an updated routes config file. Still get the same 403 error!

Comment: Then maybe it's your `photos` controller. What does that look like?

Answer (score 0):

This problem can occur if you have a directory with a name identical to the route that throws the 403 error.  Delete or rename the directory and the route will work.